# name of init function of native python module

Tags: python, cpython, python-c-api

So i'm trying to make a python binding module in C, but confused on what is the naming rule of the module init function, which is declared by `PyMODINIT_FUNC`, i've seen `init_foo`, and `initfoo`, and someone else is using `PyInit_foo`, does the name matters? which one should I follow?

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC void init_foo(void) {...}
PyMODINIT_FUNC void initfoo(void) {...}
PyMODINIT_FUNC void PyInit_foo(void) {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Extending Python with C or C++ docs(Python3)](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#the-module-s-method-table-and-initialization-function),

The initialization function must be named `PyInit_name()`, where name is the name of the module, and should be the only non-static item defined in the module file:

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_spam(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&spammodule);
}
```

You can also find the same pattern all over the [cpython source code(python3)](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?l=C&p=2&q=PyMODINIT_FUNC)

Whereas in [Extending Python with C or C++ docs(Python2)](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#the-module-s-method-table-and-initialization-function)

The initialization function must be named `initname()`, where name is the name of the module, and should be the only non-static item defined in the module file:

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC
initspam(void)
{
    (void) Py_InitModule("spam", SpamMethods);
}
```

So to answer your question the name matters. If you are writing an extension compatible to both python2 and python3 you have to implement the module init like this,

```
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION < 3
    PyMODINIT_FUNC
    init_modulename(void)
    {
        return yourmoduleinit();
    }
#else
    PyMODINIT_FUNC
    PyInit_modulename(void)
    {
        return yourmoduleinit();
    }
#endif
```

Note: `PyMODINIT_FUNC void init_foo(void) {...}` this one is actually python2 version and the module name used to import this c-extension would be `_foo`[Convention used to denote [internal c-extension]](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4a21e57fe55076c77b0ee454e1994ca544d09dc0/Modules/_statisticsmodule.c#L137)